# Question about Cauchy-Pompeiu integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to reproof the Cauchy-Pompeiu integral formula which is shown below:

Suppose that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open set and $f \in C^{1}(\Omega)$. Let $\Gamma$ be a simple, closed curve whose interior $V$ is in $\Omega$. Then for all $\zeta \in V$,
$$
f(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz - \frac{1}{\pi} \iint_{V} \frac{\partial_{\bar{z}} f(z)}{z-a} dxdy.
$$

In the proof we want to set $V_\epsilon = \{z \in V: |z - \zeta| > \epsilon \}$. Note that $V_\epsilon = V \setminus \overline{D_{\epsilon}(\zeta)}$. So I was wondering if the following is true?

$\int_{\partial V_{\epsilon}} f = \int_{\partial V} f - \int_{\partial \overline{D_{\epsilon}(\zeta)}} f$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't use text-only pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your notation! I've fixed it.

Comment: Note that $\partial V_\epsilon = \partial V \cup \partial D_\epsilon(\zeta)$, so what you are saying is true but the orientation of the integral will affect its sign. See Theorem 1.2.1 in Hormander's book *An Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables*.